# When I do the enumerate in the list which has dictionaries ,I am getting list index out of range error

Tags: python

When I loop through the dictionaries which is inside the list ,I am getting list index out of range error.I checked the previous issues it's not using the enumerate.

I tried to find the length of the list and limited to loop it within length but that didn't work.

```py
my_list = [
    {'st': '08:00', 'ed': '08:30', 'email': 'a@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '08:00', 'ed': '08:30', 'email': 'c@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '08:00', 'ed': '08:30', 'email': 'b@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '08:30', 'ed': '09:00', 'email': 'a@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '08:30', 'ed': '09:00', 'email': 'c@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '08:30', 'ed': '09:00', 'email': 'b@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '09:00', 'ed': '09:30', 'email': 'a@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '09:00', 'ed': '09:30', 'email': 'c@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '09:00', 'ed': '09:30', 'email': 'b@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '09:30', 'ed': '10:00', 'email': 'a@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '09:30', 'ed': '10:00', 'email': 'c@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '09:30', 'ed': '10:00', 'email': 'b@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '10:00', 'ed': '10:30', 'email': 'a@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '10:00', 'ed': '10:30', 'email': 'c@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '10:00', 'ed': '10:30', 'email': 'b@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '10:30', 'ed': '11:00', 'email': 'a@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '10:30', 'ed': '11:00', 'email': 'c@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '10:30', 'ed': '11:00', 'email': 'b@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '11:00', 'ed': '11:30', 'email': 'a@gmail.com'},
    {'st': '11:00', 'ed': '11:30', 'email': 'c@gmail.com'},
]
len_of_my_list = len(my_list)
for i,each_user in enumerate(my_list):
    if my_list[i]['st']==my_list[i+1]['st'] and my_list[i]['ed']==my_list[i+1]['ed']:
        if type(my_list[i]['email']) == list:
            my_list[i]['email'].append(my_list[i+1]['email'])
        else:
            my_list[i]['email'] = [my_list[i+1]['email'], my_list[i+1]['email']]
```

The expected out is ,the email id has to be merged

```
my_list = 
[{'st': '08:00', 'ed': '08:30', 'email': ['a@gmail.com','c@gmail.com','b@gmail.com']},    
{'st': '08:30', 'ed': '09:00', 'email': ['a@gmail.com','c@gmail.com','b@gmail.com']},
{'st': '09:00', 'ed': '09:30', 'email': ['a@gmail.com','c@gmail.com','b@gmail.com']},
{'st': '09:30', 'ed': '10:00', 'email': ['a@gmail.com','email': 'c@gmail.com','b@gmail.com']},
{'st': '10:00', 'ed': '10:30', 'email': ['a@gmail.com','c@gmail.com','b@gmail.com']},
{'st': '10:30', 'ed': '11:00', 'email': ['a@gmail.com','c@gmail.com','b@gmail.com']},
{'st': '11:00', 'ed': '11:30', 'email': ['a@gmail.com','c@gmail.com']}
]
```

Comment: My expected result is if st and ed are same for example first and second dictioary 'st' and 'ed' are same here then the email values has to be merged so my list should look like {'st':'08:00','ed':'08:30,'email':['a@gmail.com','c@gmail.com']}.Like this I have to compare all the dictionaries inside the list.

Comment: I have added the expected output can you please check it here?

Comment: I have added the proper output,can you check it now?

Comment: Well, it's still invalid Python, but your intent is a bit clearer, so thanks for this update. Can you fix the missing string delimiters and `'email': 'c@gmail.com'` in the middle of the list?

Comment: I fixed the missing delimiters issue also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
for i, each_user in enumerate(my_list):
    if my_list[i]['st'] == my_list[i+1]['st'] ...
```

This boils down to:

```
>>> s = "abcd"
>>> for index, letter in enumerate(s):
...     print("%d: %s, %d: %s" % (index, s[index], index + 1, s[index+1]))
...
0: a, 1: b
1: b, 2: c
2: c, 3: d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Since we know `enumerate(my_list)` iterates over the entire list, anything using `my_list[index+1]` is going to be out of bounds on the last element.

Fixing this, possibly by using `for i in range(len(my_list) - 1):`, still doesn't produce the desired outcome. The logic isn't clear to me, although the intent of assuming that the data is sorted and traversing forward is a good one.

Having said that, using a dictionary, it's pretty straightforward to group objects by time interval and build up the email lists, and is not order-sensitive:

```
grouped = {}

for e in my_list:
    key = (e["st"], e["ed"])

    if key in grouped:
        grouped[key]["email"].append(e["email"])
    else:
        grouped[key] = e
        grouped[key]["email"] = [e["email"]]

result = list(grouped.values())
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    'st': '08:00', 
    'ed': '08:30', 
    'email': ['a@gmail.com', 'c@gmail.com', 'b@gmail.com']
  }, 
  {
    'st': '08:30', 
    'ed': '09:00', 
    'email': ['a@gmail.com', 'c@gmail.com', 'b@gmail.com']
  }, 
  {
    'st': '09:00', 
    'ed': '09:30', 
    'email': ['a@gmail.com', 'c@gmail.com','b@gmail.com']
  }, 
  {
    'st': '09:30', 
    'ed': '10:00', 
    'email': ['a@gmail.com', 'c@gmail.com', 'b@gmail.com']
  }, 
  {
    'st': '10:00', 
    'ed': '10:30', 
    'email': ['a@gmail.com', 'c@gmail.com', 'b@gmail.com']
  }, 
  {
    'st': '10:30', 
    'ed': '11:00', 
    'email': ['a@gmail.com', 'c@gmail.com', 'b@gmail.com']
  }, 
  {
    'st': '11:00', 
    'ed': '11:30', 
    'email': ['a@gmail.com', 'c@gmail.com']
  }
]
```

Comment: Great. Feel free to accept the answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: I am not sure how to accept it and give a flag,can you tell me how to do it

Comment: [tour] shows how it's done, and it's the little check mark (✓) next to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are accessing the element `i+1` in the loop. Thus, once you arrive at the last element, you get said error, because there is no element `i+1` in that case.
Depending on your use case and since you don't use the variable `each_user`, you could replace the line:

```
for i,each_user in enumerate(my_list):
```

with

```
for i in range(len(my_list) - 1):
```

This will result in all but the last dictionary being compared to the next dictionary in the list.

Comment: I tried this and I am not getting any error.But the appended list is not correct. The actual output I need here is {'st':'08:00','ed':'09:00','email':['a@gmail.com','b@gmail.com','c@gmail.com'] .But the output what I am getting here is[{'st':'08:00','et':08:30','email':['a@gmail.com','b@gmail.com']},{'st':08:00','et':'08:30',email:['b@gmail.com','c@gmail.com']}].Czn you please help?